The closure of a convex cone

Let $X$ be the smallest convex cone containing $\{(z,z^2,\cdots,z^n)\in\mathbb C^n:|z|\le 1\}$, prove that $X=\mathbb C^n$.

The problem is broken down into several steps.
The second step is to prove that if $f$ is a non-zero linear functional on $\mathbb C^n$, and  $Re f(x) \ge 0, \forall x \in X$, then $\forall |z|=1, Re f((z,z^2,\cdots,z^n))=0$.
I really don't know how to prove this.

Should it be $|z|\le 1$ instead of $|z|=1$ at the end?

@Pranay It is  $|z|=1$. Or we just need to prove this when $|z|=1$. I don't know whether it is true for $|z|\le 1$.

Let $f(x) = a_1 x_1 +\cdots+a_nx_n$ for some $a_i \in \mathbb C$, with at least one of them nonzero. Then,
$$
f((z,z^2,\ldots,z^n)) = a_1 z + a_2 z^2 +\cdots + a_n z^n =: p(z),
$$
is a non-constant polynomial. Consider the image of $p(z)$ in the complex plane as $z$ goes around a circle of radius $0<r\le1$ centered at the origin. Here $r$ is chosen such that $p(z)$ has no root on the circle. Then, since $0$ is a root of $p(z)$, the image is a loop in the complex plane with nonzero winding number around the origin. That means $\Re \{p(z)\}$ must be negative at some $z$ on this circle. So the only way to have $\Re \{p(z)\}$ nonnegative is if it is zero. (Actually, $f$ itself must be zero.)

Thanks! I didn't realize that $f$ can be regarded as a polynomial.
